# Text (label) isn't being updated (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, label

I'm updating 1 field in a large database.
Since I want to see how far the progress is, I wanted to update my label ever time I updated a record.  However, this isn't working: he only updates it at the very end, when it is finished.

Note that the progress bar and the update is working perfectly, and that I don't have any error messages.  Any idea?

```
Private Sub btnUpdateHeight_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateHeight.Click
    dt = loadform()
    ProgressBarTSLabels.Minimum = 0
    Dim qty As Integer = 0
    ProgressBarTSLabels.Value = 0
    ProgressBarTSLabels.Maximum = dt.Rows.Count
    Dim db As New DataClasses1DataContext
    For Each Me.dr In dt.Rows
        If dr.Item(5).ToString.Trim <> "" Then
            Dim sqlupdate As tblLabel = (From expr In db.tblLabels Where expr.LabelID = dr.Item(0).ToString).First
            With sqlupdate
                .Height = If(dr.Item(5).ToString = "max", "999", dr.Item(5).ToString)
                db.SubmitChanges()
            End With
        End If
        ProgressBarTSLabels.Value += 1
        qty += 1
        lblQty.Text = qty & "/" & dt.Rows.Count
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `Label.Refresh` method after setting its text, which will force the label to redraw. You may also call the `Refresh` method on the progress bar too so that it works smoothly.

```
    ...
    ProgressBarTSLabels.Value += 1
    qty += 1
    lblQty.Text = qty & "/" & dt.Rows.Count
    lblQty.Refresh                     '<-- here
    ProgressBarTSLabels.Refresh        '<-- and here
Next
```

Comment: Damn, I didn't know about that option.
Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: This is one of the weirdest things I've ever seen in any language...calling a Refresh() on a label?? haha..totally needed too..unless you set the text after the code in a method runs? (This isn't related to For loops only btw) So "set info text > run code to update a data grid view" all in the same method won't update a label but "run code to update a data grid view > set info text" does work without needing Refresh()?  That's what was happening in my case.  Calling Refresh() after setting the text works whenever it's executed, which just doesn't seem necessary, but apparently it is in VB.NET.